# Geometry node 3.1: text extrude and bevel

Tags: geometry-nodes, text-object

I can't find how to reproduce the **bevel** property of usual text object in Geometry Nodes (Blender 3.1).

[image]

What I tried is this, but I can't find how to add bevel:

[image]

Comment: The bevel modifier has not yet been ported to Geometry Nodes I'm afraid

Comment: @Gorgious The question and this comment answers some questions I’ve had for a while. PTL! Thanks!

Comment: Too bad, but thanks @Gorgious! I'm wondering why Geometry nodes does not expose modifier directly in the Geometry node, I guess it would be easier to apply many things that way (and stop re-inventing the wheel).

Comment: The explanation is quite simple. The developers had to design a whole new architecture in order to ensure a level of efficiency and readability. In fact they re-did the whole design from the ground up after a few months because they noticed it didn't work. It's a relatively new tool compared to other established similar tools in other softwares. And there are a limited number of developers working on it. The order in which features are implemented may seem strange at first sight, but you have to remember they have to account for a whole spectrum of users and workflows.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation! Good luck to them then ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Well, I had this node setup to get some bevel... you could place it in a group and reuse. It's simple but far from perfect, works by extruding a couple of times and fattening some faces. It can add deformation too, so be careful.

[image: node setup]

In [the blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2nn2f9bsul0tpjj/text%20bevel.blend?dl=1) you can see how to smooth it with an extra Split Edges modifier, but you need to realize instances first to use the modifier stack. May be done with selections inside geometry nodes I guess.

And I bet there are some other setups on this...

Comment: Cool trick until blender implements bevel on curves! Thanks a lot!